# How responsible must a manager be for the result of the employees work?

Tags: management

In movies and popular 'leadership' culture, a real emphasis is on taking maximum responsibility. However what is the correct procedure for dealing with responsibility as taught by courses related to management positions?

More particularly, under the common standard, how much of the employees work quality should the manager be responsible for?

Comment: There is no "common standard". Companies vary, and even within companies, this kind of thing varies between teams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to put things in another perspective: A Manager is fully responsible for the overall deliverable/ outcome, including the quality aspect.

In other words, the quality of the final result is the responsibility of the manager. Based on scope, they can track/manage on an individual level, or overall - as a team. Example: It's a manager's responsibility to have proper QA (setup, tools and people) to ensure the quality of the deliverables. They don't necessarily need to carry out first-hand actions related to that, but need to ensure that a plan is in place to take care of that and monitor that the plan is being executed as expected.

Comment: What is the significance of the word 'deliverable'?

Comment: @Buraian That's a software/ IT specific term. You can consider that as meaningful outcome of any action.

Comment: So, you're saying the manager isn't responsibility for a single employee but rather collective output of all?

Comment: @Buraian Well, as an example it's practically impossible for a manager to oversee / manage every employee in a 150-member team. That's why there are hierarchies. When you're responsible for the overall team / outcome, you are indirectly managing all the individuals, included. So, it's not either-or, it's both.

Comment: In this post, I'm trying to figure out what the optimal leadership strategy is , does the leader put himself before his employees and take the blame for non ideal outcomes? After reading through this answer and comments on my post, I think this answer is describing the standard method as putting the manager in a position where he is responsible for overall output rather than individual work. @JoeStrazzere

Comment: The best practices talk about the manager taking responsibility for failure while praising the employees who do the good work. A lot of employees don't like it when the manager takes the praise for what they did but then is absent when the blame is thrown around.